# Where is Windows Phone Simulator for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, windows-phone-8, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin forms multi-platform project. Using Xamarin Studio Community 6.3.

The project contains three folder. Project and Project.iOS and Project.Droid.

I have implemented most of code inside the Project folder which is supposed to be shared across all platforms.

When I choose to Run the project there are only options for project.iOS and project.Droid, what about running on Windows phone? I can't seem to find that option either on Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio Community 2017.

Also when I look into some of the samples downloaded from Xamarin websites. I see included projects which are no longer supported by Xamarin Studio. I'm new to Xamarin mobile development and I used to hear that it supports all platforms including windows. So are there any major changes I should know about or any mandatory tools I may have neglected ?

[image: Xamarin Project Sample]

Comment: There is no Windows Phone emulator for macOS, that is strictly a Windows environment as the emulator runs in `HyperV`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator

Comment: So apparently I will need a windows based machine with Visual Studio installed in order to test my app on windows emulator. But also I'm currently testing the iOS version using the iOS simulator coming with the Xcode, which is not available for windows, or is there a different iOS simulator available for testing on windows ?

Comment: There is the "remote" iOS simulator that can can used from Windows/Visual Studio. You have to have a Mac available to attached to for the iOS build and simulator. You can use a Windows VM on macOS (via Parallels or VMWare) and thus code in Visual Studio running in the VM and connect the Mac "side" on the same machine for the "remote" building and simulator, but you could not use the Win-Phone emulator as it requires HyperV. You could use BootCamp on the Mac so you could enable HyperV, but now macOS is not running. To code AND test w/ Android/iOS/WinPhone at the "same" time, two PCs are needed

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Windows emulator for a mac computer.

If you have a windows computer with visual studio 2017 you can choose to install the emulator with the installer.

PS: for the second part of your questions, new things get added to Xamarin which end up in not supporting every version.

For example I use async methods to get data from WCF service en put them in my local database. Async methods are supported in Xamarin. However your computer needs at least Xamarin.Android version 4.8+ to be able to utilize async methods.

Comment: I edited your post to fix the last sentence. Xamarin.Android versions like the one you talk about (4.8+) are not the same as the version of Android OS running on a device. Xamarin.Android gets installed onto your computer and allows your computer to code and compiled using those async APIs, for example, but it has nothing to do with what version of the Android OS the device is running. The naming and versions have really confused me too in the past.

Comment: I'm indeed a little confused now. So you mean that async method won't run on KitKat ( =4.4) and that the lowest version possible is lollipop(=5.0) ?

Comment: Async will work just fine on older Android OS versions. I mean that the version of the Android OS installed on the device (Kitkat 4.4, Lollipop 5.0, etc.) do not correspond to the version of Xamarin.Android installed on your computer. So Xamarin.Android 4.8, which gets installed onto you computer, brought with it async related stuff but all Android OS versions installed on a device will more or less work with the async stuff because Xamarin.Android 4.8 has no relation to Android OS version numbers. I am probably not doing a very good job at explaining it.

Comment: So i'm currently working on a project where I use async methods. One of my bosses has an android phone with version 4.4 ( using Coloros) and the app seems to crash at the async method.

Is this a fault of me or because async can't be used in 4.4?

Comment: Our app runs on Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) and uses a whole lot of async code, all works perfectly fine. So the issue is probably with your code.